# TYPO3 - custom back end UI

Tags: user-interface, typo3, backend

I'm pretty new with TYPO3 and was wondering if you could give me an advice how to solve my problem. Basically I'm trying to make an extension that creates a custom UI for the templavoila extension. Basically my question is if you are wanting to customize the BE UI of the backend edit form, how can you possibly accomplish this? the change I wanted to make is adding another container for some options on the left side of the tabbed edit form of the generic edit page created by the class t3lib_TCEforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create a extension that extends the templavoila extension with kickstarter. Add your fields under "Extend existing Tables". Use generated tca.php file and add a --DIV-- for your new tab and fields or something you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. actually it's not just an actual tab that i need to add. I've already done that. It's another area that contains custom UI at the left side of the edit form. Meaning there's the default tabbed edit form on the right and another custom UI with options on its left side.